# Click all images to proceed? Jquery?

Tags: jquery, click, image

I have five images that when click load an include. Once the user has went through the include page they are then prompted back to the five images. All of this is using the .load() function. Once the user clicks all five images and i wish for a continue button to pop up to then proceed to the next page. How do i record a click and when five specific image is clicked a continue button pops up?

Images are set up normally in html like below.

```
<img class="img1" src="img/img1.png" />
<img class="img2" src="img/img2.png" /> 
<img class="img3" src="img/img3.png" />
<img class="img4" src="img/img4.png" />
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked into click events? What have you tried?

Comment: I know some jquery however i am sort of a noob. i understand click events. I was thinking about using indexOf().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something along the lines of the following:

**HTML**:

```
<img class="img1 notclicked" src="img/img1.png" />
<img class="img2 notclicked" src="img/img2.png" /> 
<img class="img3 notclicked" src="img/img3.png" />
<img class="img4 notclicked" src="img/img4.png" />
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('.notclicked').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('notclicked');

    if($('.notclicked').length == 0)
        // Show your button
});
```

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated and should be replaced by [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) based on your version. Please update your question to include your javascript that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a css class to the images when it is clicked. then i will check the number of items which has that purticulr class. If it is your limit (ex :5) , that means all 5 images are clicked, Now do whatever you want (show button or ..)

```
$(function(){

      $(".img1, .img2, .img3, .img4, .img5").click(function(){
        var item=$(this);
        //load image or whatever you want to do

         item.addClass("clicked");
         var totalClicked=$(".clicked").length;
         if(totalclicked==5)
         {
             alert("show /hide button");   
         }                
    });           
});
```

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/SySUS/19/

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers all deal with adding classes, I'll throw something a bit different into the mix, using jQuery's deferred objects API:

**HTML**

```
<div id='imgs_container'>
    <img src="img/img1.png" />
    <img src="img/img2.png" /> 
    <img src="img/img3.png" />
    <img src="img/img4.png" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var dfds = [];
$('#imgs_container img')
    .each(function() { dfds.push(new $.Deferred); })
    .on('click', function() { dfds[$(this).index()].resolve(); });
$.when.apply($, dfds).done(function() {
    //code to show button here
});
```

If this looks a little weird, I did a [detailed blog post](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Apr/Non-AJAX-use-for-jQuerys-deferred-objects-207) on non-AJAX uses for deferreds that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Oh too slow, here is another add class and count approach (with div instead of image) :)

http://jsfiddle.net/9T6xe/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="click-me">1</div>
<div class="click-me">2</div>
<div class="click-me">3</div>
<div class="click-me">4</div>​
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

    //elements to be clicked
    var $div = $('.click-me');


    //check if everyt div has been clicked, by checking if the num of elements with class done is equal to amount of elements
    function everyDivAlreadyclicked() {
        return $div.filter('.done').length === $div.length;
    }

    $div.bind('click', function() {

        //add done class
        $(this).addClass('done').text('clicked');

        if (everyDivAlreadyclicked()) {
            //if every div was clicked, profit!
            alert('yay done!');
        }           
    });
});​
```